# Apache subfolder as Reverse Proxy not handling RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a proxy setup on an Apache 2.4 (Server A) as follows

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyHTMLInterp On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
<Location /proxy>
    ProxyPass https://example.com
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.com
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com
</Location>
```

Server B (example.com in this example) has a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /subdir [L]
```

When I browse to https://servera.com/proxy the url changes to https://servera.com/subdir which throws a 404 error.  If I change the url to https://servera.com/proxy/subdir everything works.

My question is how can I setup Server A's proxy to preserve the /proxy in the url?

Comment: Could you rewrite it before passing it to mod_proxy?

Comment: The RewriteRule is on **Server B**.  Server A won't know what rewrite rules Server B has...or will have in the future.  I just want ALL of the content from Server B to be proxied to Server A at http://servera.com/proxy/*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/` like in the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) examples.

```
<Location /proxy/>
    ProxyPass https://example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.com/
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com/
</Location>
```

It might help in this case where the site behind the proxy redirects to an absolute path on the same hostname.

Comment: I tried adding a trailing slash without success.